# Can't install Homebrew on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, ruby

This is my first time to use Linux, I trying to install Homebrew, but it got this error :

```
Error: Failed to download ruby from the following locations:
  - https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-ruby/blobs/sha256:fc45ee6eddf4c7a17f4373dde7b1bc8a58255ea61e6847d3bf895225b28d072a
  - https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-portable-ruby/releases/download/2.6.8_1/portable-ruby-2.6.8_1.x86_64_linux.bottle.tar.gz

Do not file an issue on GitHub about this; you will need to figure out for
yourself what issue with your internet connection restricts your access to
GitHub (used for Homebrew updates and binary packages).
Error: Failed to install Homebrew Portable Ruby and cannot find another Ruby 2.6.8!
If there's no Homebrew Portable Ruby available for your processor:
- install Ruby 2.6.8 with your system package manager (or rbenv/ruby-build)
- make it first in your PATH
- try again

Failed during: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

Comment: Did you run [just `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`](https://brew.sh/)? Ubuntu fresh installation? Please add exactly the steps you run, to reproduce the issue. Running `curl -I URL` with the first return 401, but the second should work.

Answer (score 4):

fixed, in my case, this line `curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination`, just remove curl and reinstall it !

`sudo snap remove curl`

`sudo apt install curl`

Comment: This is a workaround, not really a fix. Knowing it's (it was) a snap all you'd do is to enable additional permissions.